# Hover dropdowns not working on multiple columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have been trying to get some divs to hover below my headers that have checkboxes in. I had this working:
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkbhpLtf/12/)

```
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
    let header = api.column(0).header();
    let originalText = $(header).text();
    let newText = originalText + `<div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1">
            <label for="Status1">1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2">
            <label for="Status2">2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3">
            <label for="Status3">3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4">
            <label for="Status4">4</label>
        </div>`;
    $(header).html(newText).attr("id", "hover")
}
```

However when I try to apply the same to a second header, only the last header seems to have the dropdown applied:
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkbhpLtf/14/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are trying to add multiple properties with the same name `initComplete`. In the result, you overwrite it and only the last is processed. You should put all your logic into one `initComplete` property:

```
initComplete: function(settings, json) {
    let api = new $.fn.dataTable.Api(settings);
    let header = api.column(0).header();
    let originalText = $(header).text();
    let newText = originalText + `<div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus1">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1">
            <label for="Status1">1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2">
            <label for="Status2">2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3">
            <label for="Status3">3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4">
            <label for="Status4">4</label>
        </div>`;
    $(header).html(newText).attr("id", "hover1");

    let header2 = api.column(2).header();
    let originalText2 = $(header2).text();
    let newText2 = originalText2 + `<div class="filterOptions" id="FilterStatus2">
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status1" data-status="1">
            <label for="Status1">1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status2" data-status="2">
            <label for="Status2">2</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status3" data-status="3">
            <label for="Status3">3</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="Status4" data-status="4">
            <label for="Status4">4</label>
        </div>`;
    $(header2).html(newText2).attr("id", "hover2")
}
```

Working example in [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w6t60512/1/).

Comment: I had tried that but hadn't changed the variable names in the second pass! Cheers

Comment: Glad to help :)